# How to check the status of multiple instances of Fine Uploader?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am using multiple instances of fineuploader in one page. I want to make sure that none of files are in progress in all instances of fineuploader before user clicks submit button on page. If files are completed, deleted, cancelled then its fine but it should not be in uploading status. How can I check easily?

Note : Fineuploader instances are created dynamically so it can be 2 or it can be 10

How can I check fineuploader's status -- whether its is uploading any file or not?

Comment: Hi, please show us some code, what have you tried so far? If you are trying to get simple help on how to use the script, go fetch the info on the official pages instead, it's gonna be faster.

Comment: Idea: Create a data structure that any instance of the uploader could access that would store how many files were submitted via [`onSubmit`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) / [`onSubmitted`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted) and if the [`onAllComplete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete) was emitted for that uploader. Ensure the button to proceed cannot be triggered unless that data structure shows all files have been successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data structure that any instance of the uploader could access that would store how many files were submitted via [`onSubmit`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) / [`onSubmitted`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted) and if the [`onAllComplete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete) was emitted for that uploader. Ensure the button to proceed cannot be triggered unless that data structure shows all files have been successfully uploaded.